# EF5 db.Database.SqlQuery mapping returned objects

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have two C# classes

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public int? EntityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address RegisteredAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Address
{
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
}
```

this is used in a dbContext call to map out the returning objects from a database via EF5

```
using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
{
    querySearchResult = db.Database.SqlQuery<SearchResult>(
        @"SELECT e.entity_id AS EntityId, e.entity_reg_name AS Name,
              a.address_1 AS [RegisteredAddress.Address1]
          FROM
              entity AS e
              LEFT JOIN address AS a ON e.entity_reg_addr_id = a.address_id",
        objectParameterList.ToArray()).ToList();
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I cant seem to get the address object mapped even though there is address data returned.  The other properties of the searchResult map fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SqlQuery doesn't support `Complex Type`

What you should do is:

```
internal class TempResult
{
    public int? EntityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
}

var tempResults = db.Database.SqlQuery<TempResult>(
    @"SELECT e.entity_id AS EntityId, e.entity_reg_name AS Name,
          a.address_1 AS [RegisteredAddress.Address1]
      FROM
          entity AS e
          LEFT JOIN address AS a ON e.entity_reg_addr_id = a.address_id",
    objectParameterList.ToArray()).ToList();

querySearchResult = tempResults.Select(t => new SearchResult
{
    EntityId = t.EntityId,
    [...]
    RegisteredAddress = new Address 
        {
            AddressId = t.AddressId,
            [...]
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you define complex type? If a class inherits, would the parent/base class props work? And is this still valid in EF 6.2? I can't find much about this on msdn...

Comment: what if some property is a List<SomeClass> ?