# How do I access the data from an array of objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am writing an API in C# with Visual Studios 2013 for Web.

So I have this model CurrentVisit:

```
public class CurrentVisit
{
    public Int64 visits_id { get; set; }
    public Int32 current_cycle_visits { get; set; }
    public Int32 total_visits { get; set; }
}
```

I use an SQL stored procedure to retrieve my data that I need:

```
object[] currentCycleArray = new object[visitIdArray.Length];
for (Int32 i = 0; i < currentCycleArray.Length; i++)
{
    var currentCycle = db.Database.SqlQuery<CurrentVisit>("uspApiGetCurrentVisit @member_id, @page_id, @visits_id", new SqlParameter("@member_id", memberAndPageIdentification.member_id), new SqlParameter("@page_id", memberAndPageIdentification.page_id), new SqlParameter("@visits_id", visitIdArray[i].visits_id));
    currentCycleArray[i] = currentCycle.ToArray();
}
```

Let's say visitIdArray.Length = 1;

```
object[] visits_balance = new object[visitIdArray.Length];
for(Int32 i = 0; i < visitIdArray.Length; i++)
{
   Int32 total_visits;
   for(Int32 j = 0; j < currentCycleArray.Length; j++)
   {
      if(currentCycleArray[j].visits_id == visitIdArray[i].visits_id)
      {
          total_visits = currentCycleArray[j].total_visits;
      }
   }
}
```

This seems to me like it's code that will work, but it does not. currentCycleArray[j].visits_id is not a valid property according to visual studio. The same goes for total_visits. I cannot acces my CurrentCycle fields. How is this happening?

UPDATED:

This does not work:

```
object[] currentCycleArray = new object[visitIdArray.Length];
for (Int32 i = 0; i < currentCycleArray.Length; i++)
{
    var currentCycle = db.Database.SqlQuery<CurrentVisit>("uspApiGetCurrentVisit @member_id, @page_id, @visits_id", new SqlParameter("@member_id", memberAndPageIdentification.member_id), new SqlParameter("@page_id", memberAndPageIdentification.page_id), new SqlParameter("@visits_id", visitIdArray[i].visits_id));
    currentCycleArray[i] = (CurrentVisit)currentCycle.ToArray();
}
```

OR this:

```
 object[] currentCycleArray = new object[visitIdArray.Length];
 for (Int32 i = 0; i < currentCycleArray.Length; i++)
 {
     var currentCycle = db.Database.SqlQuery<CurrentVisit>("uspApiGetCurrentVisit @member_id, @page_id, @visits_id", new SqlParameter("@member_id", memberAndPageIdentification.member_id), new SqlParameter("@page_id", memberAndPageIdentification.page_id), new SqlParameter("@visits_id", visitIdArray[i].visits_id));
     currentCycleArray[i] = (CurrentVisit)currentCycle;
 }
```

Comment: Your array is of type object, you need to make it of type CurrentVisit, or cast the content before accessing it.

Comment: My array is of type object because the query returns a System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery<CurrentVisit> type. @sondergard

Comment: Either you need to make specified typed arrays, or cast the content - I will illustrate in an answer

Comment: You need to create the CurrentVisit items manually, since SqlQuery doesn't return complex objects. Look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359522/ef5-db-database-sqlquery-mapping-returned-objects for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [DbRawSqlQuery Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn159825(v=vs.113).aspx), the DbRawSqlQuery implements IEnumerable< TElement>. This means you can iterate directly on the collection. So instead of having an object collection, you could make it a typed collection:

```
DbRawSqlQuery<CurrentVisit>[] currentCycleArray = new DbRawSqlQuery<CurrentVisit>[visitIdArray.Length];
for (Int32 i = 0; i < currentCycleArray.Length; i++)
{
    var currentCycle = db.Database.SqlQuery<CurrentVisit>("uspApiGetCurrentVisit @member_id, @page_id, @visits_id", new SqlParameter("@member_id", memberAndPageIdentification.member_id), new SqlParameter("@page_id", memberAndPageIdentification.page_id), new SqlParameter("@visits_id", visitIdArray[i].visits_id));
    currentCycleArray[i] = currentCycle;
}
```

Or you can keep the object collection, and cast the objects before accessing them:

```
object[] visits_balance = new object[visitIdArray.Length];
for(Int32 i = 0; i < visitIdArray.Length; i++)
{
   Int32 total_visits;
   for(Int32 j = 0; j < currentCycleArray.Length; j++)
   {
      var visit = (CurrentVisit)currentCycleArray[j]; // Cast to CurrentVisit
      if(visit.visits_id == visitIdArray[i].visits_id)
      {
          total_visits = visit.total_visits;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You are the man! I kept my object array and casted the objects before accessing them. Works like a charm. You saved me some migraines @sondergard

Comment: I had to cast it as var visit = (CurrentVisit[])currentCycleArray[j]; and then loop through them because it was an array of arrays. @sondergard

Comment: Ok sure, but you got the hang of it now :)