# Bind the SQL data to model property in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

Good day to you. I am returning a result as preceding from SQL stored procedure.

[image]

Now I am binding the data as follows.

```
 List<EventPhotos> resList = null;
 resList = pe.Database.SqlQuery<EventPhotos>(sqlQuery, param).ToList();
```

Following is my model.

```
public partial class EventPhotos
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public EventPhotos()
        {

        }        

        public EventInfo EventInformation { get; set; }
        public ImageInfo ImageInformation { get; set; }

    }

    public class EventInfo
    {
        public string EventID { get; set; }

        public string EventName { get; set; }

        public bool IsJoint { get; set; }
    }
    public class ImageInfo
    {
        public string ImageID { get; set; }

        public string EventMediaFolder { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }

        public string DateTime { get; set; }

        public string ImageDescription { get; set; }

        public string Action { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I run this, nothing gets mapped to my properties EventInformation and ImageInformation. Is there anyway to achieve this. I know this can be done if we use dataAdapter and assign names to the each table retrieved. But I want to use the Entity framework. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4874600/2224701

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But that is for providing the parameter. In my case the data is all fine. I am getting the data if I am using a single class with the properties. Now the problem is when I split into two properties of separate class, it is not mapping automatically.

Comment: Why do you use a raw SQL query and not linq?

Comment: I am using the same as the example in the link you provided. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Yes I am calling a stored procedure. I have mentioned it in my question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF5 db.Database.SqlQuery mapping returned objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359522/ef5-db-database-sqlquery-mapping-returned-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Try and add the table and column attributes

```
public class EventInfo
{

    [Column(Name = "EventID")]
    public string EventID { get; set; }


    [Column(Name = "EventName")]
    public string EventName { get; set; }


    [Column(Name = "IsJoint")]
    public bool IsJoint { get; set; }
}
public class ImageInfo
{

    [Column(Name = "ImageID" )]
    public string ImageID { get; set; }


    [Column(Name = "EventMediaFolder")]
    public string EventMediaFolder { get; set; }


    [Column(Name = "Image")]
    public string Image { get; set; }


    [Column(Name = "DateTime")]
    public string DateTime { get; set; }


    [Column(Name = "ImageDescription")]
    public string ImageDescription { get; set; }


    [Column(Name = "Action")] 
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

I use the below code to do the mapping

```
 returnItems = context.ExecuteQuery<EventPhotos>(sql).ToList();
```

Comment: When I try this, I am getting an error as Name is not a valid named attribute. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Vojtěch Dohnal, has answered your question really.
Both column name and table names within the attributes need to match the SQL query column names.

Comment: I am using the property names as in the select query. When I use a single class with all property, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

[Database.SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given type.
>   The type can be **any type that has properties that match the names of
>   the columns returned from the query**, or can be a simple primitive
>   type. The type does not have to be an entity type. The results of this
>   query are never tracked by the context even if the type of object
>   returned is an entity type.

It means, that the column names of the resultset of your stored procedure must match with the names of properties defined in your POCO class `EventPhotos`. So you must create the class `EventPhotos` with exact names of the returned columns instead of adding two properties - the nested properties names cannot be found by the `Database.SqlQuery` method.

SqlQuery does not support complex types.

[See a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22359522/2224701).