# How to retrieve only some fields from a table using DbSqlQuery in EF 6 (Not Linq)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Using the EF, a Rates table was created based on the Rate model below:

```
public class Rate
{
     [Key]
    public int IdNo { get; set; }
    public string RateCode { get; set; }
    public string RateClass { get; set; }
    public string Basis { get; set; }
    public bool RateIsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }
    public bool IsReservRate { get; set; }
    public decimal? CostDay { get; set; }
    public decimal? CostWeek { get; set; }
    public decimal? CostMonth { get; set; }
    public decimal? CostHour { get; set; }
}
```

I have no problem retrieving all columns from the Rates table using the code below:

```
using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
{
    DbSqlQuery<Rate> data = db.Rates.SqlQuery("select * from Rates");
}
```

but what I need is to select only two columns from the table

```
DbSqlQuery<Rate> data = db.Rates.SqlQuery("select Rate, Class from Rates");
```

and it gives me the following error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'RPManager.Models.Rate'. A member of the type, 'RateIsActive', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Is there a way to active what is needed? 
NOTE!!!! I know how to do it using Linq but for this specific case it has to be done, if possible, using db.Rates.SqlQuery()

Comment: From the method that works do you have columns Rate and Class?  Using * should give all the column names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF5 db.Database.SqlQuery mapping returned objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359522/ef5-db-database-sqlquery-mapping-returned-objects)

Comment: Would you provide Rate entity.

Comment: Only if you materialize to a class having only the subset of properties. Why would you create incomplete `Rate` entities?

Comment: @Gert Arnold To avoid sending unnecessary data over the web. Once the Rate/Class is selected, then only one row with all columns will be sufficient. But I see your point, I have applied it in other situations. If you know that this is the only way and if you publish it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: IMHO it looks like your trying to optimize this.  Do you actually have a problem that this solves or are you just pre-optimizing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to active what is needed?

Not with the code provided.  You have a few options.

Your best option:

Create a class that represents what you *need* instead of reusing a class *just because*:

```
public class RateInfo
{
  public x Rate { get; set; }
  public x Class { get; set; }
}

var data = db.Rates.SqlQuery<RateInfo>("select Rate, Class from Rates");
```

or not quite as good; set default values via the sql alias:

```
// assumming you have an Id column
var data = db.Rates.SqlQuery<Rate>("select 0 as ID, Rate, Class from Rates");
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Just need to replace var data = db.Rates.SqlQuery<RateInfo>  to var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<RateInfo>